# Принцип поиска полного URL

Tags: веб-программирование

Столкнулся с проблемой поиcка полной ссылки. Например есть строка: "google.com", - как именно происходить процесс преобразования её в: "https:\\www.google.com\", мне не ясен. Буду благодарен пару статьям на эту тему. Под процессом имеется ввиду получение протокола, стартовой страницы и всего подобного.

Answer (score 0):

1. Браузер определяет какой запрос вы вводите
2. Если запрос является неполным адресом сайта, то браузер автоматически дополняет введенную вами строку нужными доп.строками.

Например: how.ru => "https:\" + your_data + "\"

В самом деле вопрос не понятен, лучше сказать какую задачу вы решаете, а как ее решить это уже другой вопрос. Либо через JavaScript или вариант попроще через гугл таблицы.

Comment: Вопрос не втом как он автодополняет, а в том как он получает протокол и начальную страницу